# App crashes when I add <mdc:Button Text="button" IconKind="Add" /> to XAML file when using Material Design MAUI library

Tags: maui

I'm using [Material Design MAUI library](https://github.com/mdc-maui). I followed the [documentation's getting started guide](https://mdc-maui.github.io/getting-started), but for some reason, when I add `<mdc:Button Text="button" IconKind="Add" />` to my MainPage.xaml file, the app crashes. Here are my files that I modified to import the library and use it:

`MauiProgram.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Material.Components.Maui.Extensions;


namespace MyFirstMauiApp
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder.UseMauiApp<App>().ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

`app.xaml`

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyFirstMauiApp"
             x:Class="MyFirstMauiApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mdc="clr-namespace:Material.Components.Maui;assembly=Material.Components.Maui"
             x:Class="MyFirstMauiApp.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <mdc:Button Text="test"></mdc:Button>



        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

When I run the program on "Windows Machine" using Visual Studio, it runs briefly, then redirects to the `App.g.i.cs` file and highlights the `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` line of code. No program appears.

So... My question: why does this happen and how can I just get the program to run? Am I missing a bit of code, or is my configuration bad? Is something throwing an internal error? Or something else entirely?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: what exception causes the crash?

Comment: @LukeVo That's the mystery! I have no idea what error is being thrown. Here's a screen recording of what I see: https://files.catbox.moe/6yhqby.mkv

Comment: @SEUser there is an `e` parameter where it hits. You can check the value of it to see what is being thrown

Comment: @LukeVo An `e` parameter? Where and what is that?

Comment: @SEUser https://imgur.com/d4wgeJ0

Comment: @LukeVo Now I see https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5qdR.png